# How to get the e-mail header in Outlook App

Tags: javascript, outlook-2013, office-app, exchange-server-2013

How to get the e-mail header from an Office Mail App (the purpose of the app is to display some of the information found in the header)? I have failed to find any useful docs or sample on this.

As the e-mail header I mean the text which looks like this:

```
Received: from abc (def) by ghi (jkl) with mno; pqr
From: abc <def>
To: ghi <jkl>
Subject: mno
Date: pqr
Message-ID: <stu>
Accept-Language: vwx
Content-Language: yza
```

By the Outlook Mail App I mean the project created by choosing `Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 - File - New - Project - Templates - Visual C# - Office/SharePoint - Apps - Apps for Office`, choosing `Mail` as the app type and clearing all but `Email message: Read form` as where the app to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161019.aspx) to make request to Exchange server to get e-mail header.

Example for EWS header request you can find in this answer: [Read email headers in Outlook Web Access (OWA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092938/read-email-headers-in-outlook-web-access-owa)